# Access protected fields of a subclass in a superclass?

Tags: java, reflection, protected

Is it possible to access a `protected` member from `Subclass` in a `SuperClass` using reflection?

```
private void accessFields() {
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        if(Modifier.isProtected(field.getModifiers()) {
            //Will this always work? Or will get(this) throw an IllegalAccessException?
            Object value = field.get(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this would be the opposite way of the common `protected` member access, not the `SubClass` accesses the `protected` member, but the `SuperClass`.

Comment: This seems backwards since a super class should have no knowledge of nor dependence on sub classes. Why would you even want to consider this? My advise would be to re-design your code so that it wouldn't need this crazy requirement.

Comment: Sure, you can do all kinds of crazy things reflection. Like put a gun to your foot and pull the trigger. You have the code written, *try it*!

Comment: Reason is that i wanted to annotate Subclass fields so I can work with the annotated fields in the superclass. (i.e: which fields should be saved on a DB)? Bad design? Okay, I'll think about it again, thanks!

Comment: people have all the different ideas, but I find it actually a good idea for the superclass to implement a functionality which also works on all subclasses. Thats why reflection is there, to discover what you dont know in design/compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any field of an object (private, protected, public) using reflection. It doesn't matter if the class accessing the private fields of an object is its super class or sub class (when using reflection).

```
PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject("The Private Value");

Field privateStringField = PrivateObject.class.
        getDeclaredField("privateString");

privateStringField.setAccessible(true);

String fieldValue = (String) privateStringField.get(privateObject);
System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);
```

As long as you can get an object of the `PrivateObject` Class, you can access its fields. Do remember to `field.setAccessible(true)` to access non-public fields.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything with reflection. You can even directly manipulate the memory of the JVM if you feel like it (`sun.misc.Unsafe`).

However, if you don't normally have access, you'll need to use `setAccessible` or similar.